# Como instalar correctamente wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Veran, he comprado un dominio web que usare para practicar wordpress.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas son las carpetas, en las cuales ya estan las de wordpress, como wp-includes, wp-content y wp-admin.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y he creado una base de datos vacia.
Tras todo esto, deberia poder ir a la dirección bibliocan.es/wordpress, pero me encuentro con un mensaje de error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que significa este fallo?

Comment: revisaste que el archivo exista y que el usuario de ubuntu tenga acceso a el?

Comment: Es para windows, no ubuntu. Por ahora parece que he logrado solucionarlo. A ver si ahora va todo bien.